# Strange better mysql query perfomance on bigger schema

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, database-performance

I have a very strange problem with a query and MySql InnoDB schema on my server..

That query has a high query time (about 1,6 - 2 seconds), and my db is almost empty.

In order to verify performance on a bigger data set I have cloned my db, and populated it with thousand more rows. The very strange thing is that query take less time than before (0,5 seconds).

Using `explain` command on both query gives same results.

I have no idea, so where can I see any metric or difference between db??

**EDIT:**

I try to dump the `DDL` of both schema: `mysqldump -u user -ppwd -h ***** -d mySchema > mySchemaDDL.sql`

Then I have ran `diff` command about 2 dump and as result: there is no difference..

This is an example of my result:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Screenshot of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` result. Results are equals for both DB..
  [image]

Comment: Probably the first time you ran the query, your server compiled the code and created an execution plan, and then cached it.  The second time you used the cache.

Comment: I execute the query on 2 different schema, and so I have excluded that it could be a cache improvement.. Re-exceuting the query on same schema takes same time..

Comment: I have make my test after reimporting a dump of db,  I think that index statistics are reinitilized..

Comment: Run ANALYZE TABLE before each test to make sure stats are updated. Also make sure there aren't any other process on the box "polluting" you run times. To do that I would set up a test to alternate running those 1000 times in a loops and aggregating the run times to get.

Comment: When there's no query cache built, what's the result of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`?

Answer (score 1):

Databases have storage issues similiar to hard drive fragmentation. After a lot of inserts and deletes the data is stored in a suboptimal format. If you clone from a backup the new database is created in just one batch operation with an optimized internal storage. In this case mysqldump will return the same information.

You may:

- Use mysql [OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html) command
- Check for [fragmentation issues](http://blogs.technet.com/b/magi/archive/2009/05/22/fragmentation-the-database-performance-killer.aspx) in the hard disk
- Truncate the table (not just delete) and insert again all values

Comment: Table cannot be optimize because is InnoDB.. And schema is just recreated from a dump.. Than I try use the 2 db in 2 differenet server (1 Windows and 1 Linux) and on my PC.

Comment: But If I created the second DB with a dump of the original DB, and than I add thousand of row as test, I think truncate and than re-insert all value not change...

Comment: I added a 3rd option. But anyway you need to check stats, other process, locks, etc

Comment: Just in case. Do both databases and schemas have the same configuration and MySQL version?